# Save multiple screenshots

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using this code to take a screenshot with my VB app:

```
Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    screenshot.Save("c:\Screenshot.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End Sub
```

How would it be possible to save multiple screenshots in the same map? (eg. screenshot1.png, screenshot2.png, ....)

Thanks again.

PS: also if there are 2 monitors, is there a way to take a 'fullscreen' screenshot?

Comment: Add an integer called "counter" and try this `screenshot.Save("c:\Screenshot " & counter & ".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)` The problem with this dirty code is that if the item already exists it will fail unless you make a `try` and correct it or you could just overwrite it, you can have your program at start up check the destination to see what numbers have been taken and what numbers have no been taken.

Comment: Or you can append a timestamp, if that works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posting An Answer Because of the turn around time**
Even though your original code you have posted wont compile on my system, 
 With my comment as well as Pro Grammers comment, this should do the trick.

```
    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    Dim TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
    Label1.Text = TimeStamp
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    screenshot.Save("c:\Screenshot_" & TimeStamp & ".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

Have a play around with the time stamp and see what works for you.

Comment: As for your question about a multiple monitor screenshot, what have you tried?

Comment: No worries at all :)